# How to allow for MSI upgrades between every build?

Tags: windows-installer

I am currently maintaining an installer using Wise Studio 7 (in the process of changing to IS 2012 Spring)
What I am trying to accomplish is to allow QA the ability to upgrade the MSI package between each build. 
The company does not want to change the Product Code or the Version Number for each build though. 
I thought that this was possible to do with the PackageCode, but it does not seem to work. I get a message saying that a product is currently already installed. Perhaps Wise Studio's dll is getting in my way too. I don't know too much of what it does. I have tried changing its sequence and condition so that it does not run but that has not affect the output.

Currently, I have the Upgrade table set to prevent downgrades.
I also have authored to allow upgrades. 
If I keep the package code the same, the install runs in maintenance mode and QA uninstalls the previous install using the maintenance dialog. But this is not a true upgrade. 
I thought changing the packagecode should allow for small updates. But apparently my understanding is incorrect. Perhaps that is only for patch files.

Is there any way to accomplish what we desire. We really do not want to have to increment the version number. The company wants the installer version to reflect the release number of the application rather than a build version. Definately we do not want to set the Product Code GUID to a different value between builds.

Thank you for any insight.

EDIT: I should mention that we have a continuous build system.

Regards,
Dan

Comment: Note that I can get this to work if I configure this as a major upgrade and set the Product Code, Product Version and Package Code. However, this is not desireable between each build in a development cycle for testing the upgrade process for minor upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

Always test your servicing strategy.

If you plan to ship major upgrades to customers then that's what you should test.

If you plan to ship minor upgrades then that's what you should test.

I would suggest that "the company" (the infamous "they") should not concern themselves with ProductCodes.  They can concern themselves with the Major and Minor portion the ProductVersion but they should not concern themselves with the Build portion.   These two things should be reserved to CM / Install Engineering otherwise they are constraining you to fail.

Comment: Well, you are correct. In this case, historically, the company has only done major upgrades. QA has only requested minor upgrade support without having to uninstall - hmm, your point is well taken.

Comment: I was just hoping it would be easy to add support for both. Major and minor ugprades in the build system. Trying to please everyone. :)

Comment: I suppose it would be possible to build the same source twice with different inputs to create a different build outputs to support major and minor.  I'm wondering why though?  I'm also wondering what that would do to the test plan.  Upside would be to keep your options open.   Honestly I almost always do Major Upgrades only.

Answer (score 1):

You've ruled out all the possible solutions within the MSI itself.

- Changing just the package code leaves you in the realm of small updates. This will restrict the changes you can make, and makes it hard to reason about what will happen when builds are installed out of order (by your QA staff; typically you won't release multiple of these builds to the world).
- Changing the product version as well brings you to the realm of minor upgrades. This is easier to reason about (and defines an order), but just about as restrictive. However you would have to change one of the first three version parts, and you've rejected that.
- Changing the product code with each build gives you a major upgrade, which is easy to reason about, removes most restrictions, and should remove the previous automatically. This would typically be my recommendation here, unless the scenario you need to support is a minor upgrade from a previously released version.

So the questions to answer are: do you really need to reject all the MSI-based solutions, and, if so, can you provide some other approach? For instance, could you require QA to run a script or batch file which will remove the old version before launching the newly built version? Can you require QA to revert their virtual machines to a state without the previous build?

Comment: Michael thank you for the response. What I am trying to achieve is to allow QA to test a Minor Upgrade scenario between each successive build by changing the Package Code. I am not concerned so much as the install order as you are correct about these not being released to the public. I have tried changing the minor version value such as going from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 and changing the package code, but when I run the msi still returns "Another version of this product is already installed. " and they are prompted to use ARP to remove.

Comment: For a minor upgrade to work, either launch from setup.exe, or pass and appropriate `REINSTALL` on the command line. The rest brings you back to the point Chris and I both made (though he made it more explicitly): don't have your QA testing a scenario which you won't release. You don't want to waste time tracking down bugs that only exist when you go a -> b -> c -> d when only a and d are made available to the public. (QA should revert their image and test a -> b, a -> c, and a -> d separately.)